# Method in template class only for certain template parameters correct

Tags: c++, templates, template-instantiation

Consider the following template class

```
template<typename T>
struct Caller {
    void func(const T &t) { t.func(); }
    void gunc(const T &t) { t.gunc(); }
};
```

Now let some class `Target` only provide the member function `func()` but not `gunc()`, i.e.

```
struct Target {
    void func() const { /* ... /* }
};
```

is the template instantiation `Caller<Target>` valid?

GCC, clang as well as VC++ accept such template instantiations. Of course, calling `Caller<Target>::gunc()` leads to an error but `Caller<Target>::func()` works just fine and as intended.

**Now the question:** What is the background for this permissive behavior and where are the relevant paragraphs in C++ standard.

Comment: Note that you will got error with explicit instantiation: `template struct Caller<Target>;`

Answer (score 4):

It's specified in the standard, under Templates (14), Template instantiation and specialization (14.7), Implicit instantiation (14.7.1).

> 3 Unless a function template specialization has been explicitly
>   instantiated or explicitly specialized, the function template
>   specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is
>   referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist.

And

> 11 An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function
>   template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member
>   class, or a static data member of a class template that does not
>   require instantiation.

Comment: The first paragraph only refers to function templates, doesn't it? On the other hand, the second paragraph seems to explain the behavior.

Comment: No, they are function templates. It is in 14.5.1.1 - Member functions of class templates. But otherwise the second is more important for your question, as it explain why the compiler isn't allowed to generate an error message. The first would just imply that it's not required to instantiate it, but wouldn't disallow it.